# Refinerycms issue while integrating with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, refinerycms

I have configured refinerycms along with omniauth for Facebook authentication.

for the same I have created "named_routes_overrides.rb" file inside config folder.
get 'auth/:provider/callback' => "users/omniauth_callbacks#facebook"

and loading the file in application.rb file

```
initializer 'add named route overrides' do |app|
  app.routes_reloader.paths << File.expand_path('../named_routes_overrides.rb',__FILE__)
end
```

But whenever I am clicking on the link to authentication with facebook getting the following error

Couldn't find Page with ID=facebook

Using the following version:

Ruby 1.9.2
Rails 3.0.9

Answer (score 0):

This topic helped me solved similar issue with acceptance testing Omniauth on app with Refinery:
http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/browse_thread/thread/1fd21eb30d3bd9e0/d229952dc2d67477?lnk=gst&q=omniauth#d229952dc2d67477

Omniauth works for me on the app, but not within acceptance test with Capybara.